# Entering text into a UI-grid using watir automation

Tags: ruby, angularjs, automation, watir-webdriver, angular-ui-grid

We have recently changed from ng-grid to Ui-grid. This has broken lots of my automation scripts.

Currently I am having trouble entering text into a textbox.

My HTML:

```
<div 
  class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0005" 
  ui-grid-cell=""
  ng-class="{
    'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader,
    'rowError': row.entity.isValid != undefined && !row.entity.isValid }" 
  ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" 
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-selected="true">

    <div 
      class="ui-grid-cell-contents
      ng-binding ng-scope
      ui-grid-cell-focus">
    </div>
</div>
```

So I tried this, but with no joy:

```
@browser.textarea(:class,'ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope ui-grid-cell-focus').when_present.set 'test'
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Can you paste a stacktrace?

Comment: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:class=>"ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope ui-grid-cell-focus",
 :tag_name=>"textarea"} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, so the following does what i want it to:

```
@browser.div(:xpath,'html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div').when_present.click
@browser.text_field(:index,1).when_present.set 'Field 1'
```